# How can I store collections using Vuex in a way that is NOT dynamically?

Tags: redux, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

```
new Vuex.Store({
   state: {
     comments: {
         //store comments collection of each article 
         /* articleId: [...commentsCollection] */
     },
     articles: {
       ids: [],
       collection: []
     }
   },
   mutations: {
     //add a comment to comments collection of an article
     ADD_COMMENT(state, comment){
       state.comments[comment.articleId].push(comment);
       //I'm not sure if below line is needed (it works without it tho)
       Vue.set(state.comments, comment.articleId, state.comments[comment.articleId]);
     }
   }
});
```

- My first question is how come mutating an object works (here) without using Vue.set?
- Secondly while observing comments in each article with a computed property like `comments(){ return this.$store.comments[this.articleId]; }` when we update `comments` state of a specific article's comments, do other articles' comments also get updated? If that's the case isn't it bad implementation?
- Finally is there a better way to store comments?

Thanks!

Comment: What happened when you tried 2nd ?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal computed works as expected

Answer (score 2):

**Vuex Mutations**

> My first question is how come mutating an object works (here) without using Vue.set?

[Mutations follow vue's reactivity rules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html)

Which means when you make change to a property declared in your state, it will behave like a property on the vue instance was modified. So you really don't need the `vue.set` as you mention in your code snippet comments.

---

**Changes affected by mutations**

> Secondly while observing comments in each article with a computed property like comments(){ return this.$store.comments[this.articleId]; } when we update comments state of a specific article's comments, do other articles' comments also get updated? If that's the case isn't it bad implementation?

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eoycmz1L/1/), also watch the console. If I push the comment to `id = 0` the watch would tell you that the other set never had any changes made to it.

Comment: Thanks! the fiddle clearly shows that's not the case

Answer (score 1):

1)You don't need `Vue.set` because `push` method is reactive.

You can read more about `Array` reactivity here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#ad

2. Depends on your code, but shouldn't. But i think Your current implementation `comments -> article` isn't right (see 3rd)
3. I hope it's right relation `article -> comments` in your back-end (idk, may be ur project is specific and it is a necessity)

So you do need to refactor your front-end to do it like this `article->comments`

For beginning it's better to split up your store on modules `Article` and `Comment`

It's just some refactoring. If u need kind of architecture advices, then u need to provide more information, not just output\some basic actions code

Comment: 1) But as you can see the array is inside the `comments: {}` object

Comment: @user3211198 doesn't matter, vue watch for `push` event

Here is full list of reactive actions on arrays https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection

Comment: Is it gonna update all other articles' comments also?

Comment: @user3211198 i don't undersand, but how it can update other articles comments if u explicitly do `state.comments[comment.articleId].push(comment);` where is `comment.articleId` unique i think

Comment: I thought all articles would observe comments{} object change, but Amresh showed in a fiddle that's not the case. However I like the suggestion of storing comments in each article. I'll give try